# Optimizing the inner join

Tags: sql, optimization, query-optimization

The query below takes a lot of time, can anyone suggest how can I optimize it. Basically, I want the serial id where the column "TagName" is 'Station Status' and 'Leak Test Status', both have column "Value" = 'OK'. The table has two same serial id with two different (records) tag name i.e."TagName" is 'Station Status' and 'Leak Test Status'

```
select table1."SerialID" from (
        select "SerialID" from "XYZ" 
        where "StationID" IN ('01','02')
        and "TagName" = 'Station Status'
        and "TimeStamp" between '2021-05-03 09:00:00.000' and '2021-05-03 09:02:59.999'
        and "Value" = 'OK'
        ) table1
    inner join (
        select "SerialID" from "XYZ" 
        where "StationID" IN ('01','02')
        and "TagName" = 'Leak Test Status'
        and "TimeStamp" between '2021-05-03 09:00:00.000' and '2021-05-03 09:02:59.999'
        and "Value" = 'OK'
    ) table2 
on table1."SerialID" = table2."SerialID";
```

Comment: Attempt 1: Skip the subqueries. (At least some databases have problems optimizing such queries.)

Comment: Could you show us the result from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) for this query? And could you share the table and index definitions as well?

Comment: only tag the database you are using . is it mysql or postgresql?

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.  You should also explain what the code is supposed to be doing.  Sample data and desired results help.

Answer (score 2):

seems like you want to do this :

```
select "SerialID"
from "XYZ"
where "StationID" IN ('01', '02')
    and "TagName" IN ('Station Status', 'Leak Test Status')
    and "TimeStamp" between '2021-05-03 09:00:00.000' and '2021-05-03 09:02:59.999'
    and "Value" = 'OK'
group by "SerialID"
having count(distinct TagName) = 2
```

this query hit the table only once , so it should be much faster

however adding index on columns (TimeStamp,TagName,StationID,value) should help you with performance.

```
CREATE INDEX X001 ON "XYZ" ("TimeStamp", "Value", "StationID", "TagName", "SerialID")
```

Comment: Index will be better like this : CREATE INDEX X001 ON "XYZ" ("TimeStamp", "Value", "StationID", "TagName", "SerialID") --> more accurate and cover the query

Comment: @SQLpro , thank you , I didn't mean in that order , just wanted to mention the columns that need index ,

Comment: Better order for thie index coloumns:  `(Value, StationID, TagName, Timestamp)`.  That is, `=` column first; range last.